# NPM - Conditional additions to global path

Tags: node.js, path, npm

In a Node `package.json` file, you can map multiple executables to the `PATH` environmental variable on a global NPM install (`npm install -g`):

```
"bin": {
  "foo": "./bin/foo.js",
  "bar": "./bin/bar.js"
},
```

I have a unique project that requires mapping existing `PATH` variables on Operating Systems that do not have it. For example, I want to add a command named `grep` to `PATH`, *if and only if* it is being installed on a Windows computer. If the computer is running any other OS, the NPM installation will obviously fail.

---

Is there any way to run logic that pre-determines what `bin` options are available in the installation?

---

#### Oh snap - I just had an idea!

Would this work:

1. Parent module has `npm` (programmatic version) as a dependency.
2. On global installation, run a post-install script as declared in the `package.json` of parent module.
3. Post-install script does a check on the system to see which commands exist. This would be more mature than "Windows or not Windows" - it would try to exec a list of commands and see which ones fail.
4. For every command that doesn't exist, post-install script *programmatically* runs `npm install -g` on all sub-modules (one for each command, such as `grep`).

This would take a while and the `npm` module is huge, but it seems like it would work. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this directly through `package.json`, but it might be possible (and desirable) to do something like:

- Make a separate npm module for each executable you want to register (eg *my-win-grep*).
- In the *my-win-grep* module, implement the executable code you want to run, and register the `PATH`/executable value in this module.
- In the `package.json` for *my-win-grep*, include an `os` field that limits it to installing on windows.
- In your original module, list *my-win-grep* as an `optionalDependency`.

In this way, if someone installs your original module on Windows, it would install *my-win-grep*, which would register an executable to run under the `grep` command.

For users on other systems, the *my-win-grep* module would not install because of the `os` requirement, but the main module would continue to install because it ignores failures under `optionalDependencies`. So the original `grep` executable would remain untouched.

**Updated question**

This approach does sound like it should work - as you say, the npm dependency is pretty large, but it does avoid having to preform additional symlinking, and still has the benefit outlined above of having each piece of OS specific functionality in a separate module.

The only thing to watch for, possibly, in the programmatic npm docs:

> You cannot set configs individually for any single npm function at
>   this time. Since npm is a singleton, any call to npm.config.set will
>   change the value for all npm commands in that process

So this might just mean that you can't specify `-g` on your installs, but instead would have to set it globally before the first install. This shouldn't be a problem, but you'll probably need to test it out to find out exactly.

**Lastly...**

You might also want to have a look at https://github.com/lastboy/package-script - even if you don't use it, it might give you some inspiration for your implementation.

Comment: Smart. But I doubt each optional dependency would install as a global module? In order for the `my-win-grep` path to register, it would have to be globally installed. Win you `-g` install a parent package, it isn't going to globally add all child packages to `path`, is it?

Comment: True, but as per the docs it would still get symlinked locally. You could (?) then use a `postInstall` hook in my-win-grep to symlink that globally.

Comment: Good point. Can you check out my question update on the new idea you just inspired? Don't worry - I'll still accept your answer for the bounty! :)

Comment: Great advice, thanks, and `package-script` was a brilliant link. This might just work, and with depending on the NPM module.